# Multiple Arguments with Views

Tags: views

I created a views page displaying "full posts" of any content type.

Next I gave the page URL to be "test/%"

Next I added a contextual filter for Nid

- Check "Specify validation criteria" below
- "validator" set to content
- and "Filter value format" i set to "node IDs separated by , or +"

Now in my preview I put "1+2+3" and I only get node 1. Node 2 and 3 dont show up.

site.com/test/1+2+3 also only gets node 1

How can I get multiple nodes on 1 page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the '**Allow multiple values**' checkbox in the 'More' section of the contextual filter setup?  The 'More' section is collapsed by default, so it's easy to miss...

You have to check that box:

[image]